# Getting results within two dates range

Tags: mysql

`MySQL` table have 3 rows.

**Table:**

```
| ID | StartDate  | EndDate      |
|:--:|:----------:|:------------:|
| 1  | 2014-07-01 | 2014-07-31   |
| 2  | 2014-07-15 | 2014-08-15   |
| 3  | 2014-08-01 | 2014-08-31   |
```

**Visual example:**

```
| 07-01 07-31 | 08-01 08-31 |
|:-----------:|:-----------:|
| <result 1>  |             |
|         <result 2>        |
|             | <result 3>  |
```

I'm providing two dates, <kbd>Start Date</kbd> and <kbd>End Date</kbd>.

**Question:**

After setting <kbd>Start Date</kbd> to `2014-07-01` and <kbd>End Date</kbd> to `2014-07-31` I need to get `result 1` and `result 2`.

What is best way of doing this?

---

**Edit:**

End up doing this:

```
SELECT id, StartDate, EndDate FROM table

WHERE (
    (StartDate BETWEEN DATE('2014-07-01') AND DATE('2014-07-31'))
    OR
    (EndDate   BETWEEN DATE('2014-07-01') AND DATE('2014-07-31'))
);
```

Thanks to `Yograj Sudewad` and `Sadikhasan`. You guys are awesome!

Comment: `select * from your_table
    where startdate = '$datefrom'
    and enddate = '$dateend'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `query`:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN DATE('2014-07-01') AND DATE('2014-07-31');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE StartDate >= '$dateFrom' AND StartDate <= '$dateTo';
```

Comment: This will return `result 1`, but not `result 2`.

Comment: Why not? I tested it with your datas, and it's working. This will return result 1 and 2.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Misread second `StartDate` as `EndDate`. Your answer actually working as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from table_name where startdate between "2014-07-01" AND "2014-07-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from table_name where startdate ='$datefrom' and enddate='$dateto'`

Try this.